# Create a command which cycles between colors on each invocation

Tags: color

I'm trying to markup sentences in a paragraph so that each sentence in sequence gets a different color. Instead of manually specifying colors, I'd like to  simply annotate the individual sentences and have latex worry about assigning colors.

Here's a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}  

\colorlet{colorA}{red}
\colorlet{colorB}{blue}

\newcommand{\altcolorA}[1]{{\renewcommand{\altcolor}[1]{\altColorB{#1}}}\color{colorA}#1}
\newcommand{\altcolorB}[1]{{\renewcommand{\altcolor}[1]{\altColorA{#1}}}\color{colorB}#1}
\newcommand{\altcolor}[1]{\altcolorA{#1}}

\begin{document}

I want:
{\color{red}one} {\color{blue}two}
{\color{red} three}

But I get:
\altcolor{one}
\altcolor{two}
\altcolor{three}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the colors in a sequence and use modular arithmetic: at each usage of `\altcolor` a counter is stepped.

The list obeys the standard scoping rules. An `\altcolor*` variant is provided for resetting the counter to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makecolorlist}{m}
 {% #1 = color list
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_myron_colorlist_seq { , } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\altcolor}{sm}
 {% #1 = optional * for resetting, #2 = text to be colored
  \IfBooleanT { #1 } { \int_zero:N \l_myron_colorlist_int }
  \textcolor
   {% choose the color
    \seq_item:Nn \l_myron_colorlist_seq
     {
      \int_mod:nn { \l_myron_colorlist_int } { \seq_count:N \l_myron_colorlist_seq } + 1
     }
   }
   {
    #2
   }
  \int_incr:N \l_myron_colorlist_int
 }

\int_new:N \l_myron_colorlist_int
\seq_new:N \l_myron_colorlist_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\colorlet{colorA}{red}
\colorlet{colorB}{blue}

\makecolorlist{colorA,colorB}

\begin{document}

I want:
{\color{red}one} {\color{blue}two}
{\color{red} three}

And I get:
\altcolor{one}
\altcolor{two}
\altcolor{three}

Again:
\altcolor*{one}
\altcolor{two}
\altcolor{three}

\makecolorlist{colorA,colorB,green!70!red}

\altcolor*{Test} \altcolor{with} \altcolor{three} \altcolor{colors}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted Werner's answer because he was first, but this is excellent. Thanks!

Comment: @MyronLere For this reason, I rarely accept answers right away... but that's just my way of doing things... whatever works for you. :)

Comment: People get upset when you unaccept a correct answer, even for a better one. But what the hell, I'll take the fury if it comes.

Comment: @MyronLere: It's *your* decision, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only switching between two colours you can use an `\if...` condition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}  

\colorlet{colorA}{red}
\colorlet{colorB}{blue}

\newif\ifcolorA
\colorAtrue% Start with colorA
\newcommand{\altcolor}[1]{%
  \ifcolorA
    \textcolor{colorA}{#1}%
    \colorAfalse
  \else
    \textcolor{colorB}{#1}%
    \colorAtrue
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

I want:
{\color{red}one} {\color{blue}two}
{\color{red} three}

And I get:
\altcolor{one}
\altcolor{two}
\altcolor{three}

\end{document}
```